# tuning big partitioned table to make it faster

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance, partitioning, postgresql-12

I have a partitioned table, call it `Tabel1`, that is based on `partition by LIST` on `ID_X` column. This `ID_X` column is also indexed and it is part of a composite primary key with `ID_Y` column.

I do this

```
select * from pg_indexes where tablename = 'Tabel1';
```

and I find out this : `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Tabel1_pkey ON ONLY public.Tabel1 USING btree (ID_X, ID_Y)`

This table has :

- 241 GB in size,
- 92 columns (5 columns with VARCHAR(255) and 40 columns with unbounded VARCHAR)
- 13 indexes
- 1 `composite PK` (ID_X and ID_Y)
- 600 partitions
- 80.076.959 millions rows (eighty millions+)

It takes 205ms to do this query `select * from Tabel1 where ID_X = '0C37093AED94370CE050640A1502102F' limit 1`

It takes 17 minutes to do `select count (ID_X) from Tabel1`

Now, I want to optimize this table but I don't know how.

For a start, after digging here and there, I find that these statements contradicting to each other :
"*On partitioned tables, all primary keys, unique constraints and unique indexes must contain the partition expression*" **vs** *"omitting the index on the partitioning column is one of the few places where partitioning actually makes queries faster*" ([source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61454168/do-you-need-to-add-an-index-on-a-partitioned-table-postgres-11), [source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610180/postgresql-partition-table-unique-index-problem))

please help clearing up this confusion.
Postgres12

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want to "_optimize the table_"? Generally speaking, you optimize queries not tables. Are you trying to improve the performance of the `select count (ID_X) from Tabel1` operation? If so, what is your target performance, what are the 13 indexes, and where can we see the `EXPLAIN` output for the operation? Are you instead trying to consolidate indexes so that you don't have unnecessary ones? Are you trying to get clarification about those two statements at the bottom of your question? More specific focus would improve this question.

Comment: You probably don't need partitioning. You probably don't need 13 indexes. You probably should re-evaluate the design of a table with 100 columns of just `VARCHAR` fields (this smells). 80 million rows is on the smaller end for the size of a table. With the proper design and indexing, after reviewing the aforementioned suggestions, you'll probably find improvement. Please see user20042973's questions and answers accordingly, for more specific advice.

Comment: allright. I get your point @JD @user20042973. At the moment, I want a comment on the table whether its is a good set up or not, like is it OK if the `index` field (ID_X) involve in the `partition` (...`Partition BY LIST ON ID_X`) keyword? Maybe some comment on the number of `VARCHAR` fields that are so many, etc. Thanks. Pardon me

Comment: I cannot answer if your partitioning is set up well. That depends on what you want to achieve. Both of your queries won't become faster by partitioning, and the first one is bound to become slower. The more partitions, the slower.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe. Indeed, more partitons the slower it becomes. Any comment on the colomn used as `LIST partition` being indexed?

Comment: If the lists you use for list partitioning are long, the index may be useful. If the lists contain only a single item, you had better drop the index, since it is useless.

Comment: ok.. so how do I check if the `indexed partition key` is useful or not? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Run your query and see if it becomes faster with the index.